How to return two values from usememo hook using typescript and react?
i want to return two values from usememo hook using react and typescript.
i have code like below,
const renderText = (
    text: string,
    isAvailable: boolean
) => {
    let icon: IconName | undefined = undefined;
    let color: StatusColor | undefined = undefined;

    if (text === 'N/A') {
        icon = 'icon1';
        color = 'gray';
    } else if (text === 'text-1') {
        icon = isAvailable ? 'icon2' : 'icon3';
        color = isAvailable ? 'blue' : 'orange';
    }

    return (
        <>
           {icon && <Icon name={icon} color={color}/>}
           <span>{text}</Text>
        </> 
    );
};


const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({
    text, isAvailable}) => {

   return (
       <>
           {renderText(text,isAvailable)}
       </>
  );

};
the above code works fine. it returns icon and color based on text and isAvailable values.
now i want to use useMemo hook to return icon and color and use the jsx within the component instead of a seperate function renderText.
so i have tried below,
const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({
     text, isAvailable}) =>{
         const { icon, color } = React.useMemo(() => {
             let icon: IconName | undefined = undefined;
             let color: StatusColor | undefined = undefined;

             if (text === 'N/A') {
                 icon = 'icon1';
                 color = 'gray';
                 return {icon, color};
             } else if (text === 'text-1') {
                 icon = isAvailable ? 'icon2' : 'icon3';
                 color = isAvailable ? 'blue' : 'orange';
                 return {icon,color};
             },
             [text]
         );

         return (
             <>
                 {icon && <Icon name={icon} color={color} />}
                 <span>{text}</span>
             </>
         );
      };

but the above code doesnt work. it throws error cannot destruction property icon of usememo as its undefined.
i am unsure whats causing this or how to fix this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

         const { icon, color } = React.useMemo(() => {
             let icon: IconName | undefined = undefined;
             let color: StatusColor | undefined = undefined;

             if (text === 'N/A') {
                 icon = 'icon1';
                 color = 'gray';
                 return {icon, color};
             } else if (text === 'text-1') {
                 icon = isAvailable ? 'icon2' : 'icon3';
                 color = isAvailable ? 'blue' : 'orange';
                 return {icon,color};
             }
         }, [text, isAvailable]); // Also, fixed this dependency array for you

In this code, what if text has a value of "abc123"?
Then if (text === 'N/A') is not run, and also else if (text === 'text-1') is not run.
So the function returns nothing, which is implicitly undefined. and now you are tryin to deconstruct undefined which isn't going to work.

You need to ensure that all code path return a value that can be deconstructed.
Maybe something more like this?
         const { icon, color } = React.useMemo(() => {
             let icon: IconName = 'icon1';
             let color: StatusColor = 'gray';

             if (text === 'text-1') {
                 icon = isAvailable ? 'icon2' : 'icon3';
                 color = isAvailable ? 'blue' : 'orange';
             }

             return { icon, color };
         }, [text, isAvailable]);

Now there are default values that can be changed in certain circumstances, and the function always returns an object.

I would actually suggest not using useMemo and just calculating everything before returning your JSX. These are not intensive calculations so I wouldn't worry too much about trying to optimize.
I'd recommend doing:
const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({
    text, isAvailable}) => {
    let icon: IconName | undefined = undefined;
    let color: StatusColor | undefined = undefined;

    if (text === 'N/A') {
        icon = 'icon1';
        color = 'gray';
    } else if (text === 'text-1') {
        icon = isAvailable ? 'icon2' : 'icon3';
        color = isAvailable ? 'blue' : 'orange';
    }

    return (
        <>
           {icon && <Icon name={icon} color={color}/>}
           <span>{text}</span>
        </> 
    );

Or better yet, move the if/else stuff outside of the component since it can be at the module level with no issues.
function getIconAndColor(text: string, isAvailable: boolean): {icon: IconName; color: StatusColor;} {
  if (text === 'N/A') {
    return { icon: 'icon1', color: 'gray'};
  } else if (text === 'text-1') {
    return {
      icon: isAvailable ? 'icon2' : 'icon3',
      color: isAvailable ? 'blue' : 'orange',
    }
  } else {
    return {icon: 'defaultIcon', color: 'defaultColor'};
    // or you can use a switch/case
  }
}

const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({
    text, isAvailable}) => {
    const {icon, color} = getIconAndColor(text, isAvailable);
    return (
        <>
           {icon && <Icon name={icon} color={color}/>}
           <span>{text}</span>
        </> 
    );

